Bounding $ne^{-d}\left(\frac{ed}{K \log n}\right)^{K \log n}$
Apologies in advance for the nasty expression in the title. 
I'm working on Exercise 2.4.2 (p. 22) in Roman Vershinyn's High Dimensional Probability (not for a class; this is independent study). The link is to the open-source PDF of the book.
The question asks,

Consider a random (Erdos-Renyi) graph $G ∼ G(n,p)$ with expected degrees $d = O(\log n)$. Show that with high probability (say, 0.9), all vertices of $G$ have degrees $O(\log n)$.

So far, my proof proceeds as follows:
The degree $d_i$ of each node in the graph can be written as the sum of Bernoulli random variables representing whether each other node in the graph contains an edge incident to $i$.
$d_i = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \text{Bernoulli}(p)$, where $p$ is the parameter of the Erdos-Renyi graph. Further, since we know that $d$ is $O(\log n)$, there exists a $C$ for which we can write $d = C \log n$.
We want to show that with high probability, every node has a degree that grows more slowly than $O(\log n)$. Equivalently, we can show that there exists a node whose degree grows faster than $K \log n$ only with low probability.
$$\begin{align}\Pr(d_i \geq K \log n) &= \Pr\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \text{Bernoulli}(p) \geq K \log n\right)\\& \leq e^{-d_i}\left(\frac{ed_i}{K \log n}\right)^{K \log n} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(Chernoff bound)}\\ \Pr(\exists i : d_i \geq K \log n) &\leq ne^{-d}\left(\frac{ed}{K \log n}\right)^{K \log n} \qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\,\,\,\,\text{(Union bound)}
\end{align}$$
At this point, we need to show that a sufficiently large $K$ exists such that the right hand side can be bounded with arbitrarily low probability (e.g., 0.1). This is where I get stuck -- I'm able to plot the expression to show that choosing a large enough $K$ meets this criterion, I'm struggling to come up with an analytical bound on the right-hand side I can use (or another strategy) to show that for sufficiently large $K$, the right-hand side becomes arbitrarily small.
Any hints or pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks so much!!

It suffices to show $(ed/x)^x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. By taking logarithms, it also suffices to show $x \log(ed/x)\to -\infty$, which can be done using l'Hopital's Rule.

Super helpful -- thank you!!
